# Property Editor not registered with the PropertyEditorManager error on Custom Validation Tag (java)

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, jsp-tags, customvalidator

I am using TomCat 5.5 with MyFaces 1.1 and am trying to implement a custom regex validation tag.

My RegExValidator class looks like this:

```
public class RegExValidator implements Validator, StateHolder {
  private String regex;
  private boolean transientValue = false;

  public RegExValidator() {
    super();
  }

  public RegExValidator(String regex) {
    this();
    this.regex = regex;
  }

  public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object toValidate) throws ValidatorException {

    if ((context == null) || (component == null)) {
throw new NullPointerException();
    }
    if (!(component instanceof UIInput)) {
        return;
    }
    if (null == regex || null == toValidate) {
        return;
    }

    String val = (String) toValidate;

    if (!val.matches(regex)) {
        FacesMessage errMsg = MessageFactory.createFacesMessage(context, Constants.FORMAT_INVALID_MESSAGE_ID, FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, (new Object[]{regex}));
        throw new ValidatorException(errMsg);
    }
}

public Object saveState(FacesContext context) {
    Object[] values = new Object[1];
    values[0] = regex;

    return (values);
}

public void restoreState(FacesContext context, Object state) {
    Object[] values = (Object[]) state;
    regex = (String) values[0];
}

public String getRegex() {
    return regex;
}

public void setRegex(String regex) {
    this.regex = regex;
}

public boolean isTransient() {
    return transientValue;
}

public void setTransient(boolean transientValue) {
    this.transientValue = transientValue;
}
}
```

My RegExValidatorTag class looks like this:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class RegExValidatorTag extends ValidatorELTag {

private static String validatorID = null;
protected ValueExpression regex = null;

public RegExValidatorTag() {
    super();

    if (validatorID == null) {
        validatorID = "RegExValidator";
    }
}

public Validator createValidator() throws JspException {

    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    RegExValidator result = null;

    if (validatorID != null) {
        result = (RegExValidator) facesContext.getApplication().createValidator(validatorID);
    }

    String patterns = null;

    if (regex != null) {
        if (!regex.isLiteralText()) {
            patterns = (String) regex.getValue(facesContext.getELContext());
        } else {
            patterns = regex.getExpressionString();
        }
    }

    result.setRegex(patterns);

    return result;
}

public void setValidatorID(String validatorID) {
    RegExValidatorTag.validatorID = validatorID;
}

/**
 * @param regex
 *            the regex to set
 */
public void setRegex(ValueExpression regex) {
    this.regex = regex;
}
}
```

My Taglibrary Descriptor looks like this:

```xml
<tag>
    <name>regexValidator</name>
    <tag-class>com.company.components.taglib.RegExValidatorTag</tag-class>
    
    <attribute>
        <name>regex</name>
        <required>true</required>       
        <rtexprvalue>false</rtexprvalue>    
    </attribute>    
</tag>
```

My face-common-config.xml has a Validator tag like this:

```xml
<validator>
    <description>
        Validate an input string value against a regular
        expression specified by the "regex" attribute.
    </description>
    <validator-id>RegExValidator</validator-id>
    <validator-class>com.company.components.validators.RegExValidator</validator-class>
    <attribute>
        <description>
            The regular expression to test the value against
        </description>
        <attribute-name>regex</attribute-name>
        <attribute-class>java.lang.String</attribute-class>
    </attribute>        
</validator>
```

And later on it is supposed to be used in a jsp file like this:

```
<tc:in value="${dataBean.currentBean.field}">
  <a:regexValidator regex="${dataBean.currentBean.validationRegEx}" />
</tc:in>
```

When calling the page, the following error comes up:

> javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to convert string "[\d{4}]" to class "javax.el.ValueExpression" for attribute "regex": Property Editor not registered with the PropertyEditorManager
>
> Caused by:
> org.apache.jasper.JasperException - Unable to convert string "[\d{4}]" to class "javax.el.ValueExpression" for attribute "regex": Property Editor not registered with the PropertyEditorManager

I hope I provided enough details for someone to help me out on this...

Comment: I have retaged your question as the only answer doesn't help me, and the original tags didn't targeted the core of this problem. (I'm getting a similar error and am trying to fix it - using J2EE 1.4, that is JSP-2.0)

Comment: Well, no, my intuition was wrong again. I was facing a different problem that was related with the syntax I was using to set an attribute for a custom tag. I must admit I don't really know what was the cause of your (ancient) error, as I'm still not familiarized with those validators.

Comment: I also hope that I didn't remove too many of your tags: I now believe that the [tag:myfaces] indeed could be appropriate. If so, please rollback my edits (at least, this removal)

Comment: If it helps anyone, here is the description and solution to my problem: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12623908/413020

Answer (score 1):

I seem to have a similar problem like yours, I'm trying to find the solution but seems that the problem is when using Tomcat or the application server(WebSphere Application Server 7.0) JSF libraries, my problem is that the new application server has new JSF libraries (1.2) instead of the 1.1 libraries that my old application server had. (Version 6.1)

To be more specific. my problem is described here. http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21318801