# Property Editor not registered with the PropertyEditorManager: error on custom tag invokation

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, jsp-tags

I'm getting following error when invoking my `testtag.jsp`:

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to convert string "<c:out var='myvar'/>" to class "javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.JspFragment" for attribute "att1": Property Editor not registered with the PropertyEditorManager

(The detailed stack trace is irrelevant)

I'm using a J2EE 1.4 server (that is, JSP 2.0)

My `WEB-INF/testtag.tag`

```
<%@ tag body-content="scriptless" %>
<%@ tag description="Renders some test html" %>
<%@ attribute name="att1" fragment="true" required="true"  %>

<h1><jsp:invoke fragment="att1"/></h1>
```

The jsp `testtag.jsp` using this tag:

```
<%@page contentType ="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8" buffer="none" session="false" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="t" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" %>

<c:set var="myvar" value="hello world"/>
<t:testtag att1="<c:out var='myvar'/>" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to JSP.7.1.6 of the [JSP 2.0 specs](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/jsp-2.0-fr-oth-JSpec/) (bold emphasis mine),

> During the translation phase, various pieces of the page are translated into
>   implementations of the `javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.JspFragment` abstract class, before
>   being passed to a tag handler. This is done automatically **for any JSP code in the
>   body** of a *named attribute* (one that is defined by `<jsp:attribute>`) that is declared to
>   be a fragment, or of type `JspFragment`, in the TLD.

That is, in `testtag.jsp` the fragment should be passed this other way:

```
<%@page contentType ="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8" buffer="none" session="false" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="t" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" %>

<c:set var="myvar" value="hello world"/>
<t:testtag>
    <jsp:attribute name="att1"><c:out value='${myvar}'/></jsp:attribute>
</t:testtag>
```